# how to copy data into a table from another which have generated column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working on mySql workbench.

I tried to copy a table structure and its data, and created another table that has the same structure and data with:

```
CREATE TABLE 'm_syokunin_info_dev'LIKE 'm_syokunin_info'; 
INSERT 'm_syokunin_info_dev' SELECT * FROM 'm_syokunin_info';
```

It copied the table structure successfully, but I got this error for the command for the 2nd line.

```
Error Code: 3105. The value specified for generated column 'name' in table 'm_syokunin_info_dev' is not allowed.
```

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `m_syokunin_info` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `han_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `syokunin_type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(`last_name`,' ',`first_name`)) VIRTUAL,
  `isDeleted` tinytext,
  `seikyu_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mailadress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_han_id_idx` (`han_id`),
  KEY `fk_syokunin_type_id_idx` (`syokunin_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_han_id` FOREIGN KEY (`han_id`) REFERENCES `m_han` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_syokunin_type_id` FOREIGN KEY (`syokunin_type_id`) REFERENCES `m_syokunin_type` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The error says about generated column. How to copy data other than data in the generated column?

**Try1:**
I tried it specifing each column and excluding the generated column as follows. But it doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO `gas_db`.`m_syokunin_info_dev`
(`id`,
`last_name`,
`first_name`,
`han_id`,
`syokunin_type_id`,
`isDeleted`,
`seikyu_type_id`,
`mailadress`,
`group_id`)
VALUES
(select `id`,
`last_name`,
`first_name`,
`han_id`,
`syokunin_type_id`,
`isDeleted`,
`seikyu_type_id`,
`mailadress`,
`group_id`
FROM `gas_db`.'m_syokunin_info');
```

**Try2:**
I am trying to execute the following sql but it gets the syntax error. Why?

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''m_syokunin_info'' at line 20


INSERT `gas_db`.`m_syokunin_info_dev`
    (`id`,
    `last_name`,
    `first_name`,
    `han_id`,
    `syokunin_type_id`,
    `isDeleted`,
    `seikyu_type_id`,
    `mailadress`,
    `group_id`)
    SELECT `id`,
    `last_name`,
    `first_name`,
    `han_id`,
    `syokunin_type_id`,
    `isDeleted`,
    `seikyu_type_id`,
    `mailadress`,
    `group_id`
    FROM `gas_db`.'m_syokunin_info';
```

Comment: You MUST use column names list instead of asterisk in `INSERT .. SELECT`.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your comment. I tried it as you adviced. I updated the post. It didn't work though. Any mistake I made?

Comment: You must use `INSERT m_syokunin_info_dev (columns) SELECT columns FROM m_syokunin_info`, not `SELECT .. VALUES (subquery)`.

Comment: @Akina I got an syntax error for the sql that I updated again.

Comment: You use single quotes for table name quote - this is wrong. Use backticks - or none.

Comment: @Akina Thanks. Yes, the quotation marks of 'm_syokunin_info' were wrong.

Comment: Your tables/columns names does not need in quoting at all.

Comment: @Akina Yes, that's right. I am using it for bracing Japanese characters usually which I think we better to use it. But no need for alphabets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have used column names list instead of asterisk in INSERT .. SELECT, and excluding the generated column.

Working query as follows:

```
INSERT `gas_db`.`m_syokunin_info_dev`
(`id`,
`last_name`,
`first_name`,
`han_id`,
`syokunin_type_id`,
`isDeleted`,
`seikyu_type_id`,
`mailadress`,
`group_id`)
SELECT `id`,
`last_name`,
`first_name`,
`han_id`,
`syokunin_type_id`,
`isDeleted`,
`seikyu_type_id`,
`mailadress`,
`group_id`
FROM `gas_db`.`m_syokunin_info`
```